# Access position of UIButton objects in Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I have an array of `UIButtons`. What I want to do is with another button, randomly set the positions of each of the buttons in the array.

So I initialize the array with the `UIButtons`:

```
 buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7, nil];
```

Then I have a randomize method to set each of the button's positions.
this is the part where I'm stuck. I've found some threads about having to cast the type of the object in the array so the compiler understands. but I can't seem to make it work.

```
- (IBAction)randomizePositions:(id)sender 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [buttonArray count]; ++i) 
    {
        float xPos = arc4random() % 1000;
        float yPos = arc4random() % 700;
        CGRect randomPosition = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, button1.frame.size.width, button1.frame.size.width);
        (UIButton *)[buttonArray objectAtIndex:i].frame = randomPosition;
    }
}
```

It's this part here that I can't seem to get right. It's pretty obvious by now that I'm a beginner so any help would be much appreaciated.

```
(UIButton *)[buttonArray objectAtIndex:i].frame = randomPosition;
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a beginner; the key thing is that you've tried! :) Can you explain exactly what the problem is? Compiler error? Incorrect results when you run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to grab a pointer to the UIButton in the array earlier, as it might be easier to consider what you are working with.

```
- (IBAction)randomizePositions:(id)sender 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [buttonArray count]; ++i) 
    {
        UIButton *currentButton = (UIButton *)[buttonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        float xPos = arc4random() % 1000;
        float yPos = arc4random() % 700;
        [currentButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, currentButton.frame.size.width, currentButton.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

Unless, of course, you want to always be working with button1 size.

Comment: thank you for your help! this works. but I'm not sure I understand why. you're creating a new UIbutton object where you assign one of the buttons of my array into. or....?

Comment: It's not creating a new UIButton object. Rather, it is an explicit pointer to the object in the array. There's no alloc or [UIButton buttonWithType:...] called.

Comment: FWIW, `[[buttonArray objectAtIndex: i] setFrame: etc... ]` should work as well.

Comment: @JacobFennell ok, I think I understand. need to re-read the chapter on pointers thought. so is this the common way to loop through objects in an array and perform certain changes on them? so I could apply the same technique if I had an array of strings for example ,right? 

I.E. create a pointer of that object type and perform whatever I want on that pointer so that it gets passed on to the object in the array? This probably sounds a bit too simplistic.

Comment: Common way? Well, it's a way I use when I need to reference a particular object multiple times in a method or loop. Your example of an array of strings is probably not likely unless you are using the NSMutableString class type.